# Python how to add another time interval to nested while?

Tags: python

for measurement from my custom weather station I'm currently using two nested while loops to gather measuremet in 5seconds during 5min period as follows:

```
interval = 300
short_interval = 5

while True:
    start_time = time.time()

    while time.time() - start_time <= interval:
        measurement_start = time.time()
        reset_counter()
        while time.time() - measurement_start <= short_interval:
            store_directions.append(wind_direction.get_value())

        final_speed = calculate_speed(wind_interval)
        store_speeds.append(final_speed)

    measure_rain()
    do other stuff, mqtt etc.
```

which works fine - storing every 5seconds and sending everything out every 5mins

What I'm bit struggling is to accomodate another timeinterval of 60mins to gather rainfall.
Now it's measured every 5mins with measure_rain()

What would be best way how to keep 5min measurements for wind and another one for rainfall which will take 60min?
Another while? I was trying that, but ended up messing everything up ;)
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you can define each sensor as class and assign short and long intervals for each sensor. However this is CPU intensive work because of while loop without sleep.

```
import time


class wind:
    big_interval=10
    short_interval=2
    st_bigInterval=time.time()
    st_shortInterval=time.time()  

class rain:
    big_interval=10
    short_interval=2
    st_bigInterval=time.time()
    st_shortInterval=time.time()  

while True:
   
    if(time.time()-wind.st_shortInterval>wind.short_interval):
        print("collect wind data")
        wind.st_shortInterval = time.time()
      
    if(time.time()-rain.st_shortInterval>rain.short_interval):
        print("collect rain data")
        rain.st_shortInterval = time.time()

    if(time.time()-wind.st_bigInterval>wind.big_interval):
        print("send wind data")
        wind.st_bigInterval = time.time()
        wind.st_shortInterval = time.time()
  
    if(time.time()-rain.st_bigInterval>rain.big_interval):
        print("send rain data")
        rain.st_bigInterval = time.time()
        rain.st_shortInterval = time.time()
```

More better approach is to use `timeloop` as below.

```
import time
from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta

tl = Timeloop()

@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=2))
def collectWindData():
    print( "2s job current time : {}".format(time.ctime()), "collect wind data")
    
@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=5))
def sendWindData():
    print ("5s job current time : {}".format(time.ctime()), "send wind data")
    
@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=2))
def collectRainData():
    print( "2s job current time : {}".format(time.ctime()), "collect rain data")
    
@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=5))
def sendRainData():
    print ("5s job current time : {}".format(time.ctime()), "send rain data")


tl.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a task for concurrent programming. Luckily, Python has native support for it using [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently). You can either roll your own based on the event loop and the example given there, or, look at what's out there already. Two quick picks:

- [asyncio-periodic](https://github.com/vd2org/periodic) looks minimal; less than 200 LoC class; seems to do one thing (execute periodic tasks every N seconds). Not actively developed (but why would it need to?)
- [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/): much larger, but expressive syntax (`schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)`) and looking well maintained. Bigger codebase, but advertised as having no further dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

a roll your own using the built in `asyncio` module. It's a strange new way of thinking about programming and can be quite challenge to get your head around. Below is a niave implementation if you don't need to be precise on when you measured. You can make a precise version using a priority queue to put the next measurement first. A common approach to this problem is used in collision mechanics for games programming.

```
import asyncio
import random

async def measure_rain():
    while True:
        print(f'rainfall {random.randint(0,100)}') #measure rainfall
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
    return True
    
async def measure_wind():
    while True:
        print(f'windspeed: {float(random.randint(0, 100)/10)} m/s') #measure windspeed
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return True

async def main():
    tasks = []
    
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(measure_rain()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(measure_wind()))
    
    await *tasks
    
asyncio.run(main())
```